# Term to describe two circuits run through one /3 cable

Tags: electrical, wiring

For example, I have a 12/3 cable in which the red and black wires are controlled via separate breakers. The 12/3 drops into a single-gang outlet, out of which runs a 12/2 to another room. Is there a word/term for this (joined circuit, sistered circuit)?

I'm looking for a polite term ;)

(EDIT: Changed /4, /3 to /3, 2 - all cables mentioned contain grounds)

Comment: When you say "12/4 cable" and "12/3" do you mean 12/3 with ground, and 12/2 with ground?

Comment: @Tester101 - Yes, exactly.

Comment: It's an understandable confusion.  With *cordage* (flexible cords), the ground is insulated green and does count as one of the numbers.  So a refrigerator circuit goes from 14/2 in the wall to the socket, then 14/3 cordage to the fridge.  An RV goes from 6/3 in the wall to 6/4 cordage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [image]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_neutral)

> ## Split phase shared neutral (North American Wiring)
>
> In split phase house wiring, for example, a duplex receptacle in a
> kitchen is typically connected with a cable that has three conductors,
> in addition to ground. The three conductors are usually colored red,
> black, and white. The white serves as a common neutral, while the red
> and black each feed, separately, the top and bottom hot sides of the
> receptacle. Typically such receptacles are supplied from a ganged
> breaker, i.e. a breaker in which the handles are tied together for a
> common trip, so that if one kitchen appliance malfunctions and pops
> the breaker, the other side of the duplex receptacle will be shut off
> as well. This is called a multiwire circuit.

***Notes:***

*These types of circuits must use a double pole circuit breaker*

[image]

*While the NEC recognizes this configuration, there is open debate as to weather or not this is a safe practice. For more information see [Understanding the Dangers of Multiwire Branch Circuits](http://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/ET-HTML/HTML/UnderstandingDangersMultiwireBranchCircuits%7E20020218.htm)*

**EDIT**

## Multiwire circuits for 3 and 4-way switches

Switch legs, also called travelers must now be in a different color to be easily identified.  A few years ago the white wire could be used as a traveler but code changed that to lessen the confusion of identifying the traveler.  Now instead of running a piece of 14/2W/GRD or 12/2W/GRD for 3-way you have to use 14/3W/GRD or 12/3W/GRD.  Same goes for 4 Way's also.

Comment: This sounds like what I'm looking for, I think. A double pole breaker is not used however. This is original wiring (1967). I don't know whether this was acceptable then but hopefully the terms will make it easier to search. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this used to go from a new breaker box, to where the fuse box used to be.

Comment: @overslacked this wiring technique goes back a long way, and was originally used to reduce the amount of wire needed (lowering installation cost).

Comment: @lqlarry, that edit probably makes more sense as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a poor man's 220.  Are the breakers next to each other vertically in the box?  If so, then black is carrying 110 from one line, and red is carrying 110 from a second line.

Strictly speaking those lines should be fed into a single double throw breaker which covers two posts in the box.

Comment: It's not ever used as 220 - just two 110s that happen to be in the same sheath most of the way....